# Python linfunc(x) with turtle

Tags: python

So we have to do line functions with turtle, but I don't know how to do it and I just couldn't figure out how you would draw that with turtle. (I know how to do a linfunc, but not drawing with turtle, as I said)

Here is what we have to do:

> Write a program draw_linfunc.py that reads k and d of a linear
> function and draws the graph of the linear function in the interval
> -10 to +10. Write a separate function axes that draws the axes (of the coordinate system).

Here is my code, that I have used to make linfunc:

```
x = float(input("Enter your x:\n>"))
d = float(input("Enter your d\n>"))
num_x = float(input("Enter your number that you want multiply with x:\n>"))

for i in range(10):
    f = num_x * x + d
    print(f)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I may got it working now, but im not sure if it is right, can somebody please check?

```
from turtle import *

cm = 37.37

k = float(input("Enter k:\n>"))
d = float(input("Enter d:\n>"))


def plotter():
    goto(0.0, 0.0)
    penup()
    for x in range(-10,10):
        y = k * x +d
        goto(x*cm, y*cm)
        pendown()
        
        
        print(x)
        print(y)
        

def axis():
    for e in range(2):
        for _ in range(-10,10):
            write(_)
            dot()
            fd(cm)
        dot()
        write(_ + 1)
        penup()
        goto(0, -10 * cm)
        lt(90)
        pendown()


pendown()
goto(-10 * cm, 0)
axis()
plotter()
done()
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Put this into your question, and clarify: what's your question, if it works?